# get parent fields title, content excerpt etc

Tags: posts, query-posts

can't seem to get this but how can i load info in a child's page from its parent?

ie, i'm looking at an attachment and i can get the parents ID easy enough but not sure how to get the parents title, excerpt etc.

```
// attachment content above here then want to get and show some parents' content

echo $parent = get_post_field('post_parent', $id);

echo the_title(); // this still shows the childs title...
```

any help appreciated! Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `get_post($post->post_parent)` or `get_page($post->post_parent)` so if you do:

```
$parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
```

You can get the title like this:

```
$parent->post_title;
```

And anything you want, you can `var_dump($parent)` to see all the post info you can use.